# how to serialize List<T> when T is not serializable

Tags: c#, .net

**Case:**

Pass a unserializable parameter cross AppDomain.

Following is some method which i want to call in remote domain;

```
public RemoteClass
{
  public Test(Class1 obj);
  public Test(List<Class1> obj);
}
```

**Define:**

```
Class1    :   un-serializable

[Serializable]
Class2 : Class1  , ISerializable  //mark Class2 serializable
{
    //.....
}
```

**Following code used to test:**

```
using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
    f.Serialize(s, obj);
}
```

**Test result:**

```
obj                                      result

Class1 obj=new Class1();                 exception

Class1 obj=new Class2();                 success

List<Class1> obj=new List<Class1);       exception  when obj contain some element;
obj.Add(new Class1();   

List<Class1> obj=new List<Class1);       exception  when obj contain some element; //how???
obj.Add(new Class2();

List<Class2> obj=new List<Class2);       success;
obj.Add(new Class2();
```

Class1 is not a serializable calss, and I cannot modify it, so I have define Class2 which inherits from Class1 and implements ISerializable.  I can pass an instance of `Class2` when a method needs a instance of `Class1` in test result and this solution is successful, however for `List<Class1>` this does not work.

Comment: can you give us an example of Class 1 that would cause the problem and is similar to your problem? It seems your question should be - "How can I make this class serializable?"

Comment: Class1 is not serializable and i can not modify it , so  i define Class2 :Class1 , Iserializable ; now Class2 is serializable , i will pass Class2 when a  method need a Class1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about converting the `List<Class1>` instance into a list `List<Class2>` (the following should work as long as you declare a suitable constructor on `Class2`):

```
// using System.Linq;
List<Class1> inputList = MyInputList();
List<Class2> outputList = inputList.ConvertAll<Class2>(a => new Class2(a));
```

You should then be able to serialise `List<Class2>` just fine.

You find that you need to convert your serialised list back into a `List<Class>` before you can use it anywhere that accepts a `List<Class1>` - a variation on the above should work just as well in reverse.

Comment: yes i can convert List<Class1> to List<Class2> , but remote class need a List<Class1> , and i can not modify remote class

Comment: @Clover - You should defined a second remote method that accepts a `List<Class2>` - that remote method should convert the list back to a `List<Class1>` and then call the first remote method.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a [serialization surrogate](http://web.archive.org/web/20080430115634/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx) for `List<Class1>`.

Comment: This is why it's always a bad idea to include a link in an "answer" versus an actual explanation: The "serialization surrogate" link is now dead. If I find the new link, I'll post it here.

Comment: It's on archive.org, I fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

You cant serialize a `List<T>` when `T` is not serializable.

Comment: SerializationException thrown when i try to serialize List<T>,  and i can serialize T  when T is not serizalizable

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize an object, all child objects must also be serializable.

`List<T>` is serializable, but you can only serialize it if `T` is also serializable. I don't think there are any exceptions to this rule.

What reason do you have for `T` to not be serializable? In most cases all you nee to do is add `[Serializable]` above the class name and that's all you need to do!

Comment: T is defined in other component which i can not modify it

Answer (score 0):

The built in `BinaryFormatter` will not support this.  If you want to serialize classes that are not marked as `Serializable`, then you need to build a custom serializer that does not check the `Serializable` attribute.

This of course would be a lot of work.

Comment: yes , i difine a Class2 which inherit Class1 and implement ISerializable , so Class2 is serializable , but List<Class1> also is not serializable ,although real type is Class2

Answer (score 0):

If by serialize you mean, convert it to a binary format of sorts. You can do this manually using reflection. It gets tricky but can be done, even more efficiently than the built in binary serialization.

If you would like to use the standard .Net [binary serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you are out of luck, unless you are willing to add the `[Serializable]` attribute to T or implement ISerializable on T.

If you are interested in hand coding a serializer you could look at [some of the code](http://code.google.com/p/videobrowser/source/browse/MediaBrowser/Library/Persistance/Serializer.cs) I use for Media Browser. It gets tricky depending on how complex the objects you are you want to support. Would not recommend writing your own serializer unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't to that with `BinaryFormatter` - it won't let you unless the base type(s) is(/are) serializable. You could, however, serialize to xml and just pass a string or byte[] - `XmlSerializer` is less particular:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System;

public class Class1 { }
public class Class2 : Class1{}

static class Program {

    static void Main() {

        List<Class2> c2 = new List<Class2>();
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Class1>), new[] {typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2)});

        List<Class1> objects = new List<Class1>(), clone;
        objects.Add(new Class2());
        objects.Add(new Class2());
        objects.Add(new Class2());
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.Serialize(ms, objects);
            ms.Position = 0;
            clone = (List<Class1>)ser.Deserialize(ms);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Count);
    }
}
```

The difference here obviously being that `XmlSerlializer` sends the public members, not the fields. I also know my own serializer could do this for you if you want binary.

Answer (score 0):

If the buildIn Serializer is not capable of what you want, try an alternative: [sharpserializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html)